# gapi.client.youtube is undefined?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use youtube api for javascript and am getting 'gapi.client.youtube is undefined'.

I have gone through the link: [Why is 'gapi.client.youtube' from Youtube Data Api V3 undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171160/why-is-gapi-client-youtube-from-youtube-data-api-v3-undefined) , but couldn't get much help.

My code is placed below:

```
    <script>
         function load(){
          gapi.client.setApiKey('API_KEY');
          gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3');
          searchA();
        //alert(gapi.client.youtube.channels);
    }

        function searchA() {
         var q = 'pink floyd';
         var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
             part: 'statistics',
             forUsername : 'GameSprout'
         });

         request.execute(function(response) {
         var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
         alert(str);
     });
```

}

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=load">
```

But its not getting gapi.client.youtube.

Can anyone please help me in his issue?

Comment: Let me suggest not to share API keys publicly, as this may open up your API to hijacks. In case your API key is hijacked, you can disable it in google cloud console.

Answer (score 17):

The problem is that the `gapi.client.load` method takes a bit of time to complete, and it is asynchronous, so your page (which you've set up to be synchronous) is going on and running the `searchA()` method before the youtube library is fully loaded. There are two ways around this. One is to use the callback argument of the load method, like this:

```
<html>
<body>
 <script>
        function googleApiClientReady(){
                gapi.client.setApiKey('API_KEY');
                gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
                        searchA();
                });
        }
        function searchA() {
                var q = 'pink floyd';
                var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
                        part: 'statistics',
                        forUsername : 'GameSprout'
                });
                request.execute(function(response) {
                        var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
                        alert(str);
                });
        }
 </script>
```

```
</body>
</html>
```

If you'd prefer, you could also wrap a promise around the loading callback:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        googleApiClientReady=function() {
          loadApi() = function() {
                return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
                        gapi.client.setApiKey('API_KEY');
                        gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', resolve);
                });
          };
          loadApi().then(function() {
                var q = 'pink floyd';
                var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
                        part: 'statistics',
                        forUsername : 'GameSprout'
                });
                request.execute(function(response) {
                        var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
                        alert(str);
                });
          });
        };
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Also I tried making it wait for few time before executing and it worked.