# youtube api v3 search by keyword javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The javascript example for "search by keyword" that is given at the google developers page isn't working for me.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript
When I run the code, I get a disabled search box  with "cats" inside.  Also, the example doesn't explain how to write in the API key as opposed to the Client ID.  It says it's possible, but gives no concrete example of how to do it.  Can someone point out where this code is going wrong.  The code for the two .js files and the html is as follows:

auth.js file:

```
// The client ID is obtained from the Google Developers Console
// at https://console.developers.google.com/.
// If you run this code from a server other than http://localhost,
// you need to register your own client ID.
var OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '__YOUR_CLIENT_ID__';
var OAUTH2_SCOPES = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
];

// Upon loading, the Google APIs JS client automatically invokes this callback.
googleApiClientReady = function() {
  gapi.auth.init(function() {
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
  });
}

// Attempt the immediate OAuth 2.0 client flow as soon as the page loads.
// If the currently logged-in Google Account has previously authorized
// the client specified as the OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID, then the authorization
// succeeds with no user intervention. Otherwise, it fails and the
// user interface that prompts for authorization needs to display.
function checkAuth() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({
client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
immediate: true
  }, handleAuthResult);
}

// Handle the result of a gapi.auth.authorize() call.
function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
 if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
// Authorization was successful. Hide authorization prompts and show
// content that should be visible after authorization succeeds.
$('.pre-auth').hide();
$('.post-auth').show();
loadAPIClientInterfaces();
} else {
// Make the #login-link clickable. Attempt a non-immediate OAuth 2.0
// client flow. The current function is called when that flow completes.
$('#login-link').click(function() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
    scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
    immediate: false
    }, handleAuthResult);
  });
 }
}

// Load the client interfaces for the YouTube Analytics and Data APIs, which
// are required to use the Google APIs JS client. More info is available at
// http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client   /wiki/GettingStarted#Loading_the_Client
function loadAPIClientInterfaces() {
gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
handleAPILoaded();
 });
}
```

search.js file:

```
// After the API loads, call a function to enable the search box.
function handleAPILoaded() {
  $('#search-button').attr('disabled', false);
}

// Search for a specified string.
function search() {
  var q = $('#query').val();
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
q: q,
part: 'snippet'
 });

 request.execute(function(response) {
var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
$('#search-container').html('<pre>' + str + '</pre>');
 });
}
```

search.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="buttons">
  <label> <input id="query" value='cats' type="text"/><button id="search-button"  disabled onclick="search()">Search</button></label>
</div>
<div id="search-container">
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="auth.js"></script>
<script src="search.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady">  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is misleading a bit (one might even say incorrect); the HTML for the "search by keyword" is loading the same "auth.js" that the other two examples on that page are, but it doesn't then have any HTML elements to actually trigger the login process (i.e. a "login button" if a user isn't already authorized) like the other two examples do. Bascially, if you're using that provided auth.js, you need to have, in your HTML, a section that looks like this:

```
<div id="login-container" class="pre-auth">
  This application requires access to your YouTube account.
  Please <a href="#" id="login-link">authorize</a> to continue.
</div>
```

Then, you can also add the class of "post-auth" on a new div that wraps around your existing buttons and search container. The demo will then, when a user visits, only present the login link; when clicked on, and when a user allows the authorization, then the login link will be hidden and your search area will be shown (and the button enabled). That's just how the demo is set up.

Of course, search by keyword does NOT require oAuth2, and so (to answer your 2nd question) you might find it easier to A) remove the `handleApiLoaded` method (so your button is never disabled), and B) call `gapi.client.load()` manually (i.e. not triggered by an oAuth success). Then, call `gapi.client.setApiKey({YOUR KEY})` so that all of your requests will include your key in their header.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much jlmcdonald for your help.  It took me a while to figure out the second part of your response, but I finally had success.  The following html gets the example on the google developers webpage to work.  Note though, at first I was getting a 401 error.  To fix it, I had to go to the google developers console and select my project.  Then, APIs&auth->consent screen and then fill in the email address and product name:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="login-container" class="pre-auth">
   This application requires access to your YouTube account.
   Please <a href="#" id="login-link">authorize</a> to continue.
  </div>
  <div id="buttons" class="post-auth">
  <label> <input id="query" value='cats' type="text"/><button id="search-button"  disabled onclick="search()">Search</button></label>
  </div>
  <div id="search-container">
  </div>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/files/theme/auth.js"></script>
  <script src="/files/theme/search.js"></script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you noted in your response, oAuth2 isn't necessary for a simple keyword search.  The following is some html that just uses the API key.  I didn't reference the two .js files like before, rather, I just included the script in the html.  Your post at [gapi.client.youtube is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586072/gapi-client-youtube-is-undefined) really helped me figure it out:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="buttons">
  <label> <input id="query" value='cats' type="text"/><button id="search-button"  onclick="keyWordsearch()">Search</button></label>
  </div>
  <div id="search-container">
  </div>

  <script>
    function keyWordsearch(){
            gapi.client.setApiKey('API key here');
            gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
                    makeRequest();
            });
    }
    function makeRequest() {
            var q = $('#query').val();
            var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                       q: q,
                    part: 'snippet'                        
            });
            request.execute(function(response) {
                    var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
                    $('#search-container').html('<pre>' + str + '</pre>');
            });
    }
 </script>

 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now that I got the search part, could you explain how I can display the thumbnails and titles of the results and then when I click them, the video opens in an embedded player on the same page?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your coding. Let me share my code:

```js
function makeRequest(){
      var q = $('#query').val();
      var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
          q: q,
          part: 'snippet'                        
      });
      request.execute(function(response){
          var str = JSON.stringify(response.result,'',4);
          $('#search-container').val( str);
          makeControl(response);
      });
  }
  
  function makeControl(resp){
      var stList = '<table id="res1" border="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%"><tbody>'; 
      for (var i=0; i<resp.items.length;i++){
          var vid = resp.items[i].id.videoId; 
          var tit = resp.items[i].snippet.title;
          if(typeof vid != 'undefined'){    
              stList += '<tr><td style="width:80px;vertical-align:top">'+
                '<a class="show" href="#" title="'+ vid + '" onclick="playVid(this);'+
                ' return false">'+
                '<img  width="80" height="60" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+ 
                vid +'/default.jpg"></a></td>'+
                '<td><b>'+i+'</b>-'+ tit +'</td></tr>';
          }
      }
      document.getElementById('list1').innerHTML = stList + '</tbody></table>';
      //HTML: <div id="list1" 
      //style="width:853px;height:400px;overflow:auto;background-color:#EEEEEE">
      //</div>
  }
  
  function playVid(thi){
      var st = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+thi.title+'?autoplay=1';
      document.getElementById('player').src = st; 
      //HTML: <iframe id="player" width="853" height="480" src="" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen>
      //</iframe>
  }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.