# Not able to get through the sample code provided for "search" in Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to run the sample code for "search - youtube data api" using Javascript. I get the following message : "This application requires access to your YouTube account. Please authorize to continue." I get a disabled search button with text "cat" also. Now to get past this, I have read other threads also which say that oauth is not required and hence have run code as mentioned in this thread also. 
[youtube api v3 search by keyword javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975365/youtube-api-v3-search-by-keyword-javascript)

But even when i make all the changes, when i click on the authorize button, the code doesnt move any forward, A "#" gets appended in the address bar in my browser thats it and I am stuck . I am entering client ID and everything. But the code just doesnt move forward.Any help would be highly appreciated please !!

Edit-- Here is the code.

`<!doctype html>`

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="buttons">
  <label> <input id="query" value='cats' type="text"/><button id="search-button"  onclick="keyWordsearch()">Search</button></label>
  </div>
  <div id="search-container">
  </div>

  <script>
    function keyWordsearch(){
            gapi.client.setApiKey('API key here');
            gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
                    makeRequest();
            });
    }
    function makeRequest() {
            var q = $('#query').val();
            var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                       q: q,
                    part: 'snippet'                        
            });
            request.execute(function(response) {
                    var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
                    $('#search-container').html('<pre>' + str + '</pre>');
            });
    }
 </script>

 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I corrected some errors in your code, like `keyWordsearch` replace by `googleApiClientReady` and some little mistakes. I tested the code it work. Don't forget the API KEY.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="buttons">
            <label><input id="query" value='cats' type="text"/><button id="search-button"  onclick="makeRequest()">Search</button></label>
        </div>
        <div id="search-container"></div>

     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

          <script>
          function makeRequest() {
                var q = $('#query').val();
                var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                           q: q,
                        part: 'snippet'                        
                });
                request.execute(function(response) {
                        var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
                        $('#search-container').html('<pre>' + str + '</pre>');
                });
        };
        function googleApiClientReady(){
                gapi.client.setApiKey('YOUR API KEY');
                gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {});
        };
     </script>
     <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Your code does work, but there was one more reason due to which my code didnt work. The code only works when you run it from a server, even a xampp would do. But we need something like a xampp to make this work.