# Building a page that allows YouTube Search using YouTube API

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, youtube-api

What's wrong here? I am new to JavaScript and working with APIs. Any advice is greatly appreciated. I want the page to simply search youtube for the searchTerm and return matching videos to the console and add them to the Document.

Here's my HTML and JS.

HTML:

```
<body>
<form id="search-term">
    <input type="text" name="input" id="query" placeholder="Enter YouTube search here" />
    <label for="input"><input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" /></label>
</form>
<div id="search-results"> </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$(function () {
    $('#search-term').submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var searchTerm = $('#query').val();
      getRequest(searchTerm);
    }); 
});

function getRequest(searchTerm){
    var params = {
        part: 'snippet',
        key: 'AIzaSyBCaDivrcL_ivWRsuA_rw-UWH0Xr9K0iLQ',
        q: searchTerm,
//      r: 'json'
    };
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';

    $.getJSON(url, params, function(data){
      showResults(data.Search);
    }); 
}

function showResults (results) {
    var html = "";
    $.each(results, function(index, value) {
        html += '<p>' + value.Title + '</p>';
        console.log(value.Title);
    });
    $('#search-results').html(html);
}
```

});

Comment: You should take a look at XML, here's what you can do with it: https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=11&video=17093

Comment: possible duplicate of [youtube api v3 search by keyword javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975365/youtube-api-v3-search-by-keyword-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with what the API returns. The YouTube API returns correctly with what you have, but there is no `Search` on `data`. Try a `console.log(data);` in your `getJSON` and you will see that there is no `Search` object... but there are `items` which I think is what you are after here.

```
function getRequest(searchTerm){
  var params = {
    part: 'snippet',
    key: 'AIzaSyBCaDivrcL_ivWRsuA_rw-UWH0Xr9K0iLQ',
    q: searchTerm,
  //r: 'json'
  };
  url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';

  $.getJSON(url, params, function(data){
    showResults(data.items); //<-- There is no `data.Search`
  }); 
}

function showResults (results) {
  var html = "";
  $.each(results, function(index, value) {
    html += '<p>' + value.snippet.title + '</p>';
    console.log(value.snippet.title); //<-- There is also no `Title` on value.
  });
  $('#search-results').html(html);
}
```