# Return a Json response in javascript youtube api

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, javascript-objects

Hi I am using a you tube stats api to get video details.I am new to javascript.I use below function(searchstat) to get it.
I need response json when I call this searchstat funtion when I pass id.

But it returns me undefined.How can I get a json object from this function using below code.

```
var statstr = JSON.parse(searchstat(id));


function searchstat(id) {
    // Use the JavaScript client library to create a search.list() API call.
    //onClientLoad();
    //console.log(id);
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
        part: 'statistics,contentDetails',
        id: id

    });
    var ptr;
    // Send the request to the API server,
    // and invoke onSearchRepsonse() with the response.
    request.execute(function(response) {
       var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
      // return str;-->
      //ptr=str   
    });

    //return ptr;-->
}
```

I have put --> in what I have tried so far

Comment: You need to specify your Google API KEY before requesting the videos list. More info here, https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientsetApiKey

Comment: You can not return in a callback function ,when the callback function is called , your `searchstat` have already returned

Comment: When I print console.log(str) inside request.execute it prints the response but I am not able to return the json object to statstr string

Comment: @passion How can I remodel my code?

Comment: You need a callback function to handle the response .

Comment: @RajaDhasan, Alternatively you can try out this solution too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586072/gapi-client-youtube-is-undefined