# Cannot read property 'search' of undefined - Youtube API

Tags: javascript, youtube

I seem to be getting this error when trying to use JS to interact with the Youtube API. This is the console error I receive.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (app.js:7)
at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3)
at HTMLFormElement.r.handle (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3)
```

**This is the script I am using to interact.**

```
    function tplawesome(e,t){res=e;for(var n=0;n<t.length;n++){res=res.replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g,function(e,r){return t[n][r]})}return res}

$(function() {
    $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       /* prepare api request */
       var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            part: "snippet",
            type: "video",
            q: encodeURIComponent($("#search").val()).replace(/%20/g, "+"),
            maxResults: 3,
            order: "viewCount",
            publishedAfter: "2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"
       }); 
       /* execute the request */
       request.execute(function(response) {
          var results = response.result;
          $("#results").html("");
          $.each(results.items, function(index, item) {
            $.get("tpl/item.html", function(data) {
                $("#results").append(tplawesome(data, [{"title":item.snippet.title, "videoid":item.id.videoId}]));
            });
          });
          resetVideoHeight();
       });
    });

    $(window).on("resize", resetVideoHeight);
});

function resetVideoHeight() {
    $(".video").css("height", $("#results").width() * 9/16);
}

function init() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("myapikey");
    gapi.client.load("youtube", "v3", function() {
        /* check if api is ready */
    });
}
```

I was told by the person who helped me with the script initially that it has issues unless it's on an actual webserver such as Apache, but mine is so I don't understand what is causing the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, where do you reference `gapi` from? It would appear that the YouTube object is undefined. Does the API access key have the correct credential? This would need setting when creating a new application on Google console.

Comment: It's at the bottom of my HTML, sorry about that. It's definitely set up in the Google console too that's whats confusing me.

Comment: The issue will probably be to do with `client.load` being async, and your call to `search` being called when the API is not ready. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586072/gapi-client-youtube-is-undefined.

It also doesn't look like `init` is ever called. If you call this on page load you should be fine, as the search doesn't run until form submit.

Comment: Could you give me an example? Sorry, really not great at all with JS other than it being a part of my assignment.

Comment: Could you also post the HTML?

Comment: I've included it in this pastebin since I don't think my post will let me update with that much code. http://pastebin.com/XWDYnMGT

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be a lack of any call to the `init` method. Add the line `init();` above `$("form").on("submit", function(e) { ...`

I've tried this and receive an unauthorised exception as you'd expect from the dud API key.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined

Comment: Here is my example up to the point of the unauthorised error: https://jsfiddle.net/bensnaize/mznj8sw5/1/

Comment: This is where it gets me. Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:5)
    at i (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2)