# JavaScript and Google API troubles

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube-api

I'm trying to adapt a simple search script from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586072/gapi-client-youtube-is-undefined). However, I'm trying to determine why the method `loadApi` is undefined. I'm also having trouble tracking down the source of the problem, because the JS supplied by Google is... *difficult* to read.

Here is the script, once again:

```
<script>
    googleApiClientReady=function() {
      loadApi() = function() {
            return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
                    gapi.client.setApiKey('<redacted>');
                    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', resolve);
            });
      };
      loadApi().then(function() {
            var q = 'pink floyd';
            var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
                    part: 'statistics',
                    forUsername : 'GameSprout'
            });
            request.execute(function(response) {
                    var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
                    alert(str);
            });
      });
    };
</script>
```

And here is the error in question:

[image]

Comment: That question is from 2 years ago. It's likely that the google API has been updated since then, they change reasonably reguarly

Comment: The answer is just wrong. `loadApi() = function() { ...` is a syntax error.

Comment: the google docs have a [perfectly good example of how to do this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#search_by_keyword) just follow it.

Comment: @Liam The problem with the given example is that it requires 0auth to perform a search. This is silly, and I can't implement a search function that requires a login.

The other issue with the search function in the example is that it doesn't allow for a search of an individual channel, which is a requirement of this script.

Comment: @JJJ I'm very, *very* new to JavaScript, I'm sorry :)

Comment: But you do need to authenticate.... So you **need** to use OAuth...Maybe this is why you can't get it working?

Comment: @Liam I need to authenticate just to perform a search? Why? Additionally, isn't the presence of the api key enough?

Comment: @Wolfish I don't think you need to be authenticated to list channels.   Only if you wish to see information about the channel I believe basic data is public.

Comment: Because google needs a way to control who's accessing their system and how many times, etc. to prevent people abusing it. Basically why? Because Google say so. Don't like it, email Google. Also OAuth isn't necessarily authentication, it's key based so in it's simplest form it's more of an identification mechanism

Answer (score 1):

It may not require authentication to preform a search but your application still needs to be reregistered and you will need to at the very least use an API key.

Kindly note I a **not** a JS dev I just copied this example from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication#simple-access-using-the-api-key).  There are several that show how to access [public apis](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#LoadinganAPIandMakingaRequest).

```
gapi.client.init({
 'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
  ...
}).then(...)
```

Note: [channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) is a part public part private method as far as I can see.   Some of the parameters will only work if you are authenticated .

> mine   boolean
>   This parameter can only be used in a properly authorized request. Set this parameter's value to true to instruct the API to only return channels owned by the authenticated user.