# YouTube API v3 javascript - OAuth not working

Tags: javascript, api, oauth, youtube

I was studying how to make a simple search using YT API v3 and I took a look at https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/javascript then I gave it a shot using ExpressJS (with localhost:5000 properly authorized in GCP) and creating an API Key and OAuth credentials on GCP, but when I ran the tests it gave a strange error when the following function was executed:

```
// Handle the result of a gapi.auth.authorize() call.
function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  //Here I printed the authResult to see what was going on
  console.log(authResult)
  if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
    // Authorization was successful. Hide authorization prompts and show
    // content that should be visible after authorization succeeds.
    $('.pre-auth').hide();
    $('.post-auth').show();
    loadAPIClientInterfaces();
  } else {
    // Make the #login-link clickable. Attempt a non-immediate OAuth 2.0
    // client flow. The current function is called when that flow completes.
    $('#login-link').click(function() {
      gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
        scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
        immediate: false
        }, handleAuthResult);
    });
  }
}
```

And It gave me the following Object when I printed the variable authResult:

```
>{
  "error": "immediate_failed",
  "error_subtype": "no_user_bound",
  {
  "error": "immediate_failed",
  "error_subtype": "no_user_bound",
  "status": {
    "signed_in": false,
    "method": null,
    "google_logged_in": false
  },
  "client_id": "MY_CLIENT_ID",
  "cookie_policy": "single_host_origin"
}
```

Where in "MY_CLIENT_ID" I put my OAuth Client ID. I really don't know how to fix that issue and I searched all over stackoverflow and the closest thing that I found was [gapi.client.youtube is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586072/gapi-client-youtube-is-undefined) .

Answer (score 0):

It tries to authenticate on page load with `immediate: true`, but the page does not have permission yet, hence the error. If you click the `#login-link` element, it should then bring up the oauth flow to allow permissions. Then, on subsequent page reloads, the error should not appear.