# gapi.client.youtube is undefined in angular app

Tags: angular, google-api-js-client

**Note: I know the subject looks similar to that other question, but it is different**

I have angular app that calls Google API (gapi).

I have functions that call gmail api, calendar api and youtube api.

Here I have 2 questions:

**Question1**: Why is **youtube** here **unrecognizable**?
Although I have all the types installed:

[image]

[image]

**Question2**: When running the app, gmail api and calendar api calls work fine, but youtube api call throws an error that **youtube** is undefined?

```
getMessages() {
    return gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({ userId: 'me', labelIds: ['INBOX', 'UNREAD'] }).then();
}
getEvents() {
    return gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list().then();
}

getChannels() {
    return gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({'part': 'snippet', 'mine': 'true'}).then();
}
```

For some reason in getChannels() function I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of **undefined**
```

where **gapi.client.youtube** is undefined.

gapi is defined, client too, but youtube is not.

Any help is appreciated. As you can see there is no difference in how these apis are called, same signature, dont understand why youtube is undefined.

Here is the screenshot in debug mode

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gapi.client.youtube is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586072/gapi-client-youtube-is-undefined)

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:**

Checking the [@types/gapi.client.youtube](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/gapi.client.youtube/index.d.ts#L27), the correct should be (at least what is defined in the type definition):

```
gapi.client.channels.list(null).then()
```

**Update**
As discussed in the comments, I also believe the type definition is wrong and you should extend it in your project (until the definition is fixed)

**Answer 2:**
Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586072/gapi-client-youtube-is-undefined) helps you

Comment: According to documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps it should be 'gapi.client.youtube.channels.list', otherwise it doesnt work either.

Comment: probably an error at type definition? last commit comes from 2019

Comment: youtube is defined as namespace of gapi.client exactly the same way as calendar defined in @types/gapi.client.calendar or as gmail is defined in @types/gapi.client.gmail

Comment: I know the subject looks  similar to that other question, but it is different

Comment: @types/gapi.client.youtube is not defined the same way as @types/gapi.client.calendar.
Look at the end of the `youtube` namespace, there are no constants, while, in the end of `calendar` namespace we do have it

Comment: yes, you are right, with gmail constants are defined inside gmail namespace, while with youtube, constants are defined outside of youtube namespace. Not sure why. Also, its unclear why in the original documentation they use gapi.client.youtube.channels.list() and not gapi.client.channels.list(). Which one is correct then, I want to believe that the documentation is correct, but in this case I cannot use @types and have to declare gapi as "any" or gapi.client as "any". but in this case I am loosing intellisense and type checking, not sure if it will work.

Comment: Tried gapi.client.channels.list() after declaring gapi:any. Cannot use intellisense or type checking, but now in runtime I get "channels" is undefined... something is wrong here. actually on the screenshot of debugger above I am not using @types, and gapi is declared as 'any', however on the right side, under the 'watch' panel, there is no channels property, however there is gmail and calendar.

Comment: I would rather believe in the documentation as well. You can open an issue to the repo and, in the meanwhile, extend the namespace with the corrent constants

Comment: And for the runtime problem, I would double check the load method. The problem must be there

Answer (score 0):

I believe gapi is not meant to be used with node or Angular. Try [Google APIs Node.js Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#google-apis-nodejs-client)

Edit: Not standalone, but here is a [related thread](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1270) with updates and [instructions](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1270#issuecomment-653443879)

Comment: This thread has nothing to do with what I am talking about. I dont even know what library they are using. There is no such thing as `import { google }` or the rest of what they are talking about in original gapi which is pure javascript. I am using original Google API (gapi) for javascript with no problem, everything works just fine.

Comment: You wouldn't be here if everything was indeed working just fine. I'm keeping this here incase someone stumbles upon this, just so they can have options were they willing to try alternatives. As I stated already, I believe gapi is not a good fit for Node and Webpack environments.

Comment: As for what library they're using, just as gapi is [Google API Client Library for JavaScript](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client#google-api-client-library-for-javascript), the googleapis library I linked in my answer is the [Node.js client library for using Google APIs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#google-apis-nodejs-client). And yes, it's official, as evident by its use in [this guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs#step_2_install_the_client_library)

Answer (score 0):

Before you use gapi.client.youtube you must call init function :

```
gapi.load('client', () => {
  gapi.client.init({
    apiKey: *****,
    clientId: *****,
    discoveryDocs: *****,
    scope: *****,
  });
});
```

then in your  gapi.client.youtube.channels.list() Request you should send the token with it:

```
gapi.client.youtube.channels
    .list({
        mine: true,
        part: 'statistics',
        access_token: //SAVED-TOKEN,
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log('channels', res);
    });
```